# GAN - Python crashes without error message and with strange exit code when using keras.Sequential.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

My Python code crashes without an error message. My only command line output is the following:

> 2022-07-16 09:11:13.307094: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild
> TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2022-07-16
> 09:11:13.832861: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1342 MB memory:  ->
> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce MX330, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0,
> compute capability: 6.1 2022-07-16 09:11:13.911731: W
> tensorflow/core/kernels/data/cache_dataset_ops.cc:768] The calling
> iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to
> avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached
> contents of the dataset  will be discarded. This can happen if you
> have an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`.
> You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.
>
> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

The code is the same as the one in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AALBGpLbj6Q) tutorial and is represented below:

```
# Bringing in tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
# Brining in tensorflow datasets for fashion mnist
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
# Bringing in matplotlib for viz stuff
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Do some data transformation
import numpy as np
# Bring in the sequential api for the generator and discriminator
from keras import Sequential
# Bring in the layers for the neural network
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Reshape, LeakyReLU, Dropout, UpSampling2D


# Scale and return images only
def scale_images(data):
    image = data['image']
    return image / 255


def build_generator():
    model = Sequential()

    # Takes in random values and reshapes it to 7x7x128
    # Beginnings of a generated image
    model.add(Dense(7 * 7 * 128, input_dim=128))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
    model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))

    # Upsampling block 1
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    # Upsampling block 2
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    # Convolutional block 1
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 4, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    # Convolutional block 2
    model.add(Conv2D(128, 4, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    # Conv layer to get to one channel
    model.add(Conv2D(1, 4, padding='same', activation='sigmoid'))

    return model


gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

# Use the tensorflow datasets api to bring in the data source
ds = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', split='train')

var = ds.as_numpy_iterator().next()['label']

# Setup connection aka iterator
data_iterator = ds.as_numpy_iterator()


# Getting data out of the pipeline
var2 = data_iterator.next()['image']


# Setup the subplot formatting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20, 20))
# Loop four times and get images
for idx in range(4):
    # Grab an image and label
    sample = data_iterator.next()
    # Plot the image using a specific subplot
    ax[idx].imshow(np.squeeze(sample['image']))
    # Appending the image label as the plot title
    ax[idx].title.set_text(sample['label'])
# plt.show()


# Reload the dataset
ds = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', split='train')
# Running the dataset through the scale_images preprocessing step
ds = ds.map(scale_images)
# Cache the dataset for that batch
ds = ds.cache()
# Shuffle it up
ds = ds.shuffle(60000)
# Batch into 128 images per sample
ds = ds.batch(128)
# Reduces the likelihood of bottlenecking
ds = ds.prefetch(64)

generator = build_generator()

# Generate new fashion
img = generator.predict(np.random.randn(4, 128, 1)) # crash happens here
```

Someone in the comments received the following error message at the same line:

> UnimplementedError: Graph execution error: Node:
> 'sequential/conv2d/Conv2D' DNN library is not found.   [[{{node
> sequential/conv2d/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_140492]

Here, the youtuber suggested his machine might be OOM. My MX330 has only 2GB of RAM available, but I modified all the parameters in the build_generator function and the problem persists. CUDA and cudNN were installed manually and ever since I don't get the CUDA warning anymore, so I guess it was installed fine.

I tried with different scripts, but they all seem to fail on the same step, when calling the predict function, or something similar.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I tried running `python -u -m trace -t program.py` in order to trace where python crashes, but it runs on infinite loop.

Update 2: I finally got another error when starting my program from command line:

> Could not locate zlibwapi.dll. Please make sure it is in your library path!
> I will try downloading the missing dlls and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running `python myScript.py` in command line and I got errors related to dlls not installed. So I moved them from the cudNN installation folder to the CUDA installation folder and now everything works just fine.